# Lambda development in AWS -? develop locally? or use AWS web console

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-ses

How do people develop usually?
Do they use something like serverless or use AWS Lambda ( web console on AWS Platform).

I am facing challenges with testing on local especially simulating the SQS triggerring of Lambda, and SES.
I am developing an eco system where an API will send a message to SQS. 
SQS will trigger a Lambda function, and this function will send out a customer registration email.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [node-lambda](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-lambda).  It makes it easy to develop/test locally and then deploy to AWS.

One thing to note is that your *.env* file will contain your AWS settings such as lambda config, memory, etc.  Then you can create *deploy.env* which will contain any ENVs for your lambda to use.  If you run *node-lambda setup*, those env files will be created for you.

This is what my scripts looks like in my *package.json*:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV=dev node-lambda run --configFile deploy.env",
    "deploy": "node-lambda deploy --configFile deploy.env"
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)  . Does this support using Lambda environment variables? As we have different DB and URL, path etc for DEV, UAT and PRODUCTION systems. Can Lambda version support environment variables? I noticed that when I created new version, I could not see the "environment variables" section in AWS web console.

Comment: Terraform does support lambda env variables.  See lambda doc [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/lambda_function.html), you're looking for environment field.